# El código se modifica solo y queda almacenado con ese nuevo cambio

Tags: laravel, blade, laravelcollective

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
{!! Form::model($text, [
    'route' => ['text.update', $text->id], 
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'files' => true
]) !!}
```

Y al abrir la página modifica el código por este:

```
{!! Form::model($text ?? '', [
    'route' => ['text.update', $text ?? ''->id], 
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'files' => true
]) !!}
```

Y me muestra el siguiente error:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

También pasa con otras variables del mismo `$text` en la misma página.

`

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en `$text`?¿Es una variable que devuelves de un controlador?

Comment: Es una variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenía por algún motivo dos versiones del sitio mezcladas

Answer (score 0):

Probaste eliminando la cache? desde la terminal ejecuta estos comandos

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

Por otra parte si eso no funciona podrías quizás cambiar el nombre de la variable

Comment: Me faltó view:clar, lo hice con config y cache

Comment: me muestra el mismo error pero no altera el código... Debo ver que pasa porque el dd($text) en el controlador no funciona

Comment: mm si esta extraño quizas collective no se te instalo bien